# Drupal: How to format email message using node invite module?

Tags: drupal

I am using the node invite and token module.
I have followed this flash tutorial video: http://www.adevbox.com/files/2008-06-25_1703.swf

My problem is regarding the email format being sent.

In the ?q=admin/settings/node_invite
I have checked the blog entry checkbox. Now the node invite works but I can't format my body section value correctly.

For example:
I entered in the textarea

```
Hi &lt;bold&gt;
```

Then the result when I open the email message is still the same:

```
Hi &lt;bold&gt;
```

Same with if I use `<b>bold here</b>` then it will also be the format when I open the email message.

How can I format it correctly? Am I missing something simple? I am thinking of using htmlspecialchars but I don't where to put it.
Thanks in advance :)

Kind Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the Invite module is that there is no Input Filter for the template. This means that the only format that is accepted is plain text. This means that it will convert HTML into the escaped code you see.

You can validate this looking at the variables in the database. Your best bet it so path Invite (or ask for a features) to allow HTML as a valid format.